# Showing $P(A\cap C)\geq P(A)P(C)$ from $A \cap B \subset C \subset A \cup B$ without using the independence of $A$ and $B$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Here is the problem I came across:

> Let $A,B,C$ be events in some probability space. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent and $A \cap B \subset C \subset A \cup B$ then $P(A\cap C)\geq P(A)P(C)$.

My text gives a relatively lengthy solution using both of the givens.

I came up with the following solution which doesn't make use of the independence of $A$ and $B$:

\begin{align} 
P(A)P(C) & = P\Big((A\setminus C)\cup (A \cap C)\Big)P\Big((C\setminus A)\cup (A \cap C)\Big)
\\ & = P(A\setminus C)P(A \cap C)P(C\setminus A)P(A \cap C)
\\ & \leq P(A \cap C)
\end{align}

Clearly, not using some of the given is mostly a huge red flag. Yet I don't see what's wrong with my solution. Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: Note that a counterexample for the case where $A,C$ are not independent is very easy to construct: simply take two mutually exclusive events with positive probabilities and get that $P(A \cap C) = 0$ whereas $P(A)P(C)>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using something like $P((A \setminus C) \cup (A \cap C)) = P(A \setminus C)P(A \cap C)$ which is wrong. It is true, however, that $P((A \setminus C) \cup (A \cap C)) = P(A \setminus C) + P(A \cap C)$.

Comment: Shame on me. And thank you.